# How do I take 10% fee of paypal transaction

Tags: paypal

I am implementing the Paypal checkout system onto my site. Basically there is a seller, buyer, and my business. When the seller puts up something to sell and the buyer buys something, I (the business) get 10% of what the buyer pays. Is there a option in the Paypal api, or do I have to do it another way?

Comment: You mean like paying the seller once the buyer's payment is confirmed?

Comment: No, Once the buyer pays, I get 10% of the money and the seller gets the rest! So the business gets a 10% commission.

Comment: AFAIK you would need two transactions obtain this result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Chained Payments in the Adaptive Payments API:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/

> Chained payments enable a sender to send a single payment to a primary receiver. The primary receiver keeps part of the payment and pays secondary receivers the remainder. For example, your application could be an online travel agency that handles bookings for airfare, hotel reservations, and car rentals. The sender sees only you as the primary receiver. You allocate the payment for your commission and the actual cost of services provided by other receivers. PayPal then deducts money from the sender's account and deposits it in both your account and the secondary receivers' accounts.